# Is there a way to shorten this?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I am currently using the following code to display a dialog in WPF:

```
Dim wAbout As New About
wAbout.ShowDialog()
```

Is there a way to shorten this to one statement only?

Already tried `New About.ShowDialog()` and `(New About()).ShowDialog()`, won't work.

I am using VBv10 if that may help.

Comment: Tried parentheses? Not that i have a clue about vb...

Comment: Reducing code artificially to a single line often decreases readability. In this case, it also prevents you from properly disposing of the About Window object.

Comment: You could create a new class that calls ShowDialog() in the constructor.

Comment: This is how to do it in C# `new About().ShowDialog()` just as a reference.

Comment: You can create a static method ShowDialog and establish and pass the instance of you wAbout in it, hiding the complexity inside. Much of muchness. VB.NET it's not designed to be sharp at its name suggests.

Comment: If that is the case, you better look into the Factory Pattern.

Comment: @andrew barber disposing objects in .net shouldn't be a concern

Comment: would it?:) at least you can do everything by one line of code.

Comment: @sjums Ummm... what? If a class implements IDisposable, you should call Dispose() on it when done with it (with certain, rare exceptions).

Comment: dim showabout = (New About).ShowDialog()

Comment: @Andrew Barber never mind, I misunderstood something..obviously :b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the [Call keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxz296wz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this purpose:

```
Call New About().ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 3):

No, in Visual Basic declaring the variable and then running a method against it in two separate lines is the shortest way you can do that. But that's probably good because making the code one line would make it less readable.

Comment: Agree, going that route you'd never be able to justify the existance of lambdas though;)

Answer (score 1):

This seem to work for me:

```
Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
     Dim a = (New About).ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: This gets the requested job done, but honestly... don't do that. It looks like your setting the value of `about` equal to a property called `ShowDialog`.